# error while sending data to web service

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk2006r2

using bizTalk 2010 orchestration:
when i send data port configured as webservice the following error appear

> The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port >"WcfSendPort_Service_ServiceSoap12" with URL "blablabla/Service.asmx". It will >be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port. >Details:"System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
>    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
>     at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
>     at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
>     at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
>     at >Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BizTalkBodyWriter.ValidateStreamContainsXml(Stream >stream)
>     at >Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfMarshaller.CreateWcfMessage(CreateWcfMessageSetti>ngs settings)
>    at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.SendRequestMessage(IBaseMessage >bizTalkMessage, IRequestChannel channel)
>     at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.SendMessage(IBaseMessage >bizTalkMessage)".

Comment: and the message of schema of wcf is:<ns0:sendMessage xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/">
  <ns0:phoneNumber>phoneNumber_0</ns0:phoneNumber> 
  <ns0:message>message_0</ns0:message> 
  </ns0:sendMessage>

Answer (score 2):

The crucial part of the exception is:

> System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.

This suggests that you are not transmitting what you think you are transmitting.

From the Suspended Message Instance, check that the message body that being sent is what you expect; or - change your Send Port Adapter to FILE and write the message out to the file system in order to check the message content.

Comment: the instance arrive to send message is:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <Records xmlns="">
  <PhoneNumber>123456786</PhoneNumber> 
  <Message>how are you</Message> 
  </Records>

Comment: and the message of schema of wcf is:<ns0:sendMessage xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/">
  <ns0:phoneNumber>phoneNumber_0</ns0:phoneNumber> 
  <ns0:message>message_0</ns0:message> 
  </ns0:sendMessage>

Comment: i change the wcf adapter to file then it work, but with wcf adapter didn't work!!

Comment: It looks like you're missing a map to transform <Records><PhoneNumber>.... into <sendMessage><phoneNumber>. You can add a map on the Send Port that is transmitting the message via the WCF Adapter.

Comment: Is it transforming from  <Records><PhoneNumber>.... into <sendMessage><phoneNumber>?

Comment: Nick is right, "Root element is missing" basically means that the message you are getting does not contain any data (no XML root).

If you keep the same pipeline with a FILE adapter and a message shows up, this means you should probably try and find the problem in your adapter properties. This can be a variety of things to be honest.